# Function that creates a list of all indexes where an element appears in a list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am attempting to write a function `(positions N A L)` which returns a list of each index that A appears in L and N is the number that is given to the first element of L.

For example,

`(positions 0 'a '(a b c a d e a))` => `(0 3 6)`

`(positions 1 'a '(a b c a d e a))` => `(1 4 7)`

So far, I have come up with this (which isn't working correctly):

```
(define (positions N A L)
  (cond
    ((null? L)
     '())
     ((= (car L) A)
      (cons N (positions (+ N 1) A (cdr L))))
     (#t
      (positions (+ N 1) A (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: Please give details as to how this function's behavior differs from what you want.

Comment: You are comparing arbitrary objects (symbols in this case) using `=`, which is actually reserved for numbers. Try using `eqv?` instead. Or consider passing in the test function as additional (optional) argument.

Comment: Also, the `#t` in the last clause of the `cond` wants propably to be `else` (i.e. `(cond ((...) ...) ... (else ...))`)

Comment: @Dirk That is the solution! I had tried using `eq`, `eqv`, `eql` and `equal` but forgot to add the `?` to all of them! And what would be the difference in using `#t` or `else` in this case? If the function reached that point, you would want it to always move onto the next element of the list and check it. In other words, if that point is reached, you would want it to always be evaluated as true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (positions N A L)
  (cond
    ((null? L)          '())
    ((equal? (car L) A) (cons N (positions (+ N 1) A (cdr L))))
    (else               (positions (+ N 1) A (cdr L)))))
```

The problem was that `=` is defined only for numbers. If you're certain that that the list will only contain symbols, use `eq?`. Otherwise use `equal?`, which is the most general equality comparison and works for many data types (numbers, symbols, booleans, etc.) Also, use `else` for the last condition, using `#t` is a Common Lisp convention that doesn't apply in Scheme.